# State managment for screen on React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, optimization, state-management

on project we have need use architecture, where getting data from API display on screens and storage in locale state. How this architecture implementing on React Native with using state managment libraries.

P.S. For data, with getting from API, we cannot be used global state.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [React-Query](https://react-query.tanstack.com/installation#npm) for fetching data and [React.Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext) for storing and providing data to children.

For a persistent storage you can use [AsyncStorage](https://reactnative.dev/docs/asyncstorage)